# AMP Carousel :: Dynamically add item

Tags: jquery, amp-html

I am using AMP, Onclick of **Add slide**, I need to add slide to the carousel dynamically.

**Carousel is not working:**

[image]

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '#addNewSlide', function(){
  jQuery('amp-base-carousel').prepend('<amp-img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ji_G7Bu1MoM/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-base-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-base-carousel-0.1.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:;" id="addNewSlide">Add slide</a>
<amp-base-carousel loop="true"  width="300" height="400"></amp-base-carousel>
```

Comment: You can't run jquery in AMP. You have to isolate the needed jquery subset, code it as vanilla JS, and then integrate your `addNewSlide` code with the jquery subset in the - now - single JS code black.

Comment: /s/code black/code block/

Comment: @JayGray, Thanks for the comment. Sadly, as project has been developed in jQuery based, I cannot avoid the using the jQuery. Can you please let me know if any other approach?

Comment: Put the carousel in an `amp-live-list` container; load all existing slides from the list (to verify you have it working correctly); then - server-side - add a new slide to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="addNewSlide" u>Add slide</a>
<amp-live-list layout="container" data-poll-interval="15000" data-max-items-per-page="5" id="amp-live-list-insert-blog>
 <button update on="tap:amp-live-list-insert-blog.update">You have updates</button>
 
 
</amp-live-list >
```

For the HTML update the **update on**

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#addNewSlide', function(){
  jQuery('amp-live-list').prepend('<amp-img src="https://source.unsplash.com/Ji_G7Bu1MoM/600x400" width="600" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>')
})
```

Update the `apm-base-coursel` to `amp-live-list`